# Play Framework 2 field grouping

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2

I have a "group" of the following inputs:

- text input 1
- text input 2
- checkbox

Text input 1 is always required. Text input 2 is only required if the checkbox is checked.  How can I achieve this type of validation with play? Currently I have something like this:

```
val myForm: Form[MyData] = Form(
  mapping(
    "text1" -> text.verifying("Text1 is required", !_isEmpty),
    "text2" -> text.verifying("Text2 is required", !_isEmpty),
    "check" -> boolean
)
```

But clearly this is not what I want since it will *always* require text2. Is there a way to compose this to achieve this interdependent validation?

**update based on wheaties suggestion:**
This solution worked, however it has some quirks that I need to overcome:

1. The ad-hoc validation doesn't occur until all of the other constraints in the form pass.  If the other constraints fail, the ad-hoc validation doesn't even execute.  I need them all to execute together so I can show all the error messages on the form.
2. The error that gets assigned during this ad-hoc validation does not apply to the specific form input, e.g. text2. In my template, I need to show an error message on text2 saying something like ("since you checked the checkbox, you need to fill out this input"). Rather, the error is just a general "form-level" error. You can imagine I'll have multiple instances of this type of validation so I can just assume that this error applies to text2.

I looked at the custom validators the play supports, but I do not see how I can use them to operate across multiple fields.  [The example they show](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaCustomValidations) applies only the the form field that is being validated with no obvious way to reference other inputs in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see from the documentation that they allow for ad-hoc validations on the form objects you create (see [documents](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaForms).) What you can do is make a validator:

```
 def validate(text1: String, text2: String, check: Boolean) = if(check) text2.nonEmpty else true

 val myForm: Form[MyData](
   mapping("text1" -> text.verifying("Text1 is required", !_isEmpty))
 )(MyData.unapply)(MyData.apply) verifying ("Text2 is required if check box checked", {
   case data => validate(data.text2, data.check)
 })
```

which should give you what you want but I'd also check out their [custom validators](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaCustomValidations) section as well (since they recommend this as a good route to follow.)

Comment: This worked generally but with a couple issues: the ad-hoc validation happens only _after_ all the other non-ad-hoc validations pass (so I won't know about the error unless everything else is ok).  Also, this validation doesn't "apply" to a specific field e.g. text2 -> in other words I want to be able to show an error on the form next to text2, but this error appears to be a form-level error, not field level.  I suspect that maybe a custom validator can help, but I do not see how I can use them to validate across multiple fields (the custom validator seems to operate only on a single field).

Comment: @oym You could move that `validate` method onto the `MyData` class itself and then invoke that predicate expression as a validator (if there is a validator that accepts arbitrary predicates.)

Comment: would you mind expanding on that a bit, maybe with an example? I am not sure how to start with that: how do I use this validate method etc.  Thanks

Comment: I got it working using a combination of nested mappings and the ad-hoc validation you suggest applied to the nested mapping